# TypeError: booster must be Booster or LGBMModel

Tags: scikit-learn, lightgbm

I have a LightGBMclassifier and want to plot its features importance,
for that, I used the line bellow :

```
import lightgbm as lgb

lgb.plot_importance(model, figsize=(8,6))
```

but I get this error :

```
TypeError: booster must be Booster or LGBMModel.
```

can someone help please ? I do not get this error.

and here's how I built the model :

```
   lgbmc_classifier = LGBMClassifier(
        boosting_type='goss',
      colsample_bytree=0.17,
      lambda_l1=69.12,
      lambda_l2=0.0001,
      learning_rate=0.09,
      max_bin=512,
      min_child_samples=3,
      n_estimators=7782,
      num_leaves=10,
      subsample=0.26,
      random_state=356,
      importance_type='gain',
    )

model = Pipeline([
    ("preprocessor", preprocessor),
    ("standardizer", standardizer),
    ("classifier", lgbmc_classifier),
])

#model



model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

##################################################

for data processing, on the model pipeline I also use :

```
for col in ["Time_Taken_hours", "Date"]:
    timestamp_transformer = TimestampTransformer()
    ohe_transformer = ColumnTransformer(
        [("ohe", OneHotEncoder(sparse=False, handle_unknown="ignore"), [timestamp_transformer.HOUR_COLUMN_INDEX])],
        remainder="passthrough")
    timestamp_preprocessor = Pipeline([
        ("extractor", timestamp_transformer),
        ("onehot_encoder", ohe_transformer)
    ])
    transformers.append((f"timestamp_{col}", timestamp_preprocessor, [col]))


from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(transformers, remainder="passthrough", sparse_threshold=0)
```

###################################################

```
standardizer = StandardScaler()
```

Comment: How did you fit / create the "model" variable? The error suggests that "model" is not of type "Booster" or "LGBMModel". Can you add that to the question?

Comment: I have just added it !

Comment: "model" is of class Pipeline, not "Booster" or "LGBMModel". You need to get the model, which would be model["classifier"] I suppose, so you could plot the importance using lgb.plot_importance(model["classifier"], figsize=(8,6))

Comment: thank you for your answer, but i'm not really sure how to do that :/

Comment: @tavdp how would you go from that pipeline into a booster ? plz

Comment: I mean you could just copy/paste, but I'll formulate an actual answer, just a sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your error, `model` is not of the type that `lgb.plot_importance` expects, namely `Booster` or `LGBMModel`.

This is kind of clear, since you define `model` by

```
model = Pipeline([
    ("preprocessor", preprocessor),
    ("standardizer", standardizer),
    ("classifier", lgbmc_classifier),
])
```

The `Pipeline` function returns a class `Pipeline` instead of `Booster` or `LGBMModel` [Pipeline](https://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html#sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline).

But you need `LGBMModel` or `Booster`. So how do you get that? Well, you gave it the name `classifier`, hence you can access it using `model["classifier"]`. This is what you can use:

```
import lightgbm as lgb
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

X_train, y_train = load_iris(return_X_y=True)

lgbmc_classifier = lgb.LGBMClassifier(
    boosting_type='goss',
    learning_rate=0.01,
    min_child_samples=10,  
    n_estimators=100,
    num_leaves=10,
    random_state=1,
    importance_type='gain',
)
lgbmc_classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

model = Pipeline([
    ("classifier", lgbmc_classifier)
])

lgb.plot_importance(model['classifier'], figsize=(4,2))
```

returns

[image]

Note that I have tweaked your regularization parameters a bit in order to be able to gain some results on the iris dataset. Also, I removed the two other Pipeline elements as I don't know how you use, them, but for the result that doesn't matter in this case.

You could also just get the data, and match the data with the feature columns, e.g. using plotly:

```
import plotly.express as px
importances = pd.DataFrame({"feature_names": X_train.columns, "values": lgbmc_classifier.feature_importances_})
fig = px.bar(importances, x="feature_names", y="values" , width=400, height=400)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Or maybe you wanted a pie chart instead

```
fig = px.pie(importances, names="feature_names", values="values" , width=400, height=400)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer, :) for the two other ("preprocessor", preprocessor),
    ("standardizer", standardizer), from the model pipeline, i actually need them for data processing and standardization,

Comment: I just added the code related to the data processing and standardization I used on my pipline

Comment: I actually could not fit the data without the two other parameters of  my model pipeline, so it still doesn't work :(

Comment: But that is another question. Also it doesn't change the answer to the original question.

Comment: well, the lgb.plot_importance(model['classifier'], figsize=(4,2)) is working for me, but printing the name of the columns as "COLUMN0 , COLUMN1 ..." is not understandable, as originally i have 145 columns, after a model.named_steps["classifier"].feature_names I get over 999 columns !!!

Comment: You could always just get the data using `lgbmc_classifier.feature_importances_`, combine these with the column names, and use some kind of plotting library such as plotly or matplotlib or plotnine, whatever you like, then plot using these. That is what I would do anyway if you wanted to export the insights.

Comment: I have tried this : for feat, importance in zip(df_loaded.columns, model.named_steps["classifier"].feature_importances_):
    print ('feature: {f}, importance: {i}'.format(f=feat, i=importance)) and it's seems to be okay, thank you for your help,